# mkdir: cannot create directory '/ffa_app': Permission denied

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to create a Dockerfile for an app which I want to run inside the docker. I am running the app using the command activator run.
and this command is inside the file structure
`xyz\Desktop\ffa_predix\activator-1.2.10`.
So, I have gone inside the file and put my Dockerfile there with the following content.

```
FROM jboss/base-jdk:7

RUN mkdir -p /ffa_app

COPY . /ffa_app

WORKDIR /ffa_app

CMD ["activator" , "run"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

But after going to the second line it's giving me the error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/ffa_app': Permission denied.

Comment: Why do you need the `mkdir` command if you already have `COPY` later in your dockerfile ?

Answer (score 3):

The [user set by the base image](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/base-jdk/blob/54f63f6c4a0e69505c64fb092c50a868132a12a3/Dockerfile#L11) is `jboss`, so you have 2 options:

- create and work in the user's home folder `mkdir -p ~/ffa_app`
- set `USER root` at the top of your Dockerfile, after the `FROM` statement

Needless to say, I'd recommend sticking to a user with lower privileges.